# How do I make a UIWebView look like the one in FaceBook app?

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview

when tapping on external links within FaceBook. A UIWebView appears with navigational controls on the bottom and a Share Arrow in the bottom right.

The Share Arrow reveals

1. Open in Safari
2. Share Link
3. Copy Link
4. Cancel

Is this a new view or an overlay to an existing view?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a custom UIViewController with a UIWebView embed in it.... You can do it even from the IB and with a custom toolbar and navigationbar.

Do you need any specific info on it? :)